# How do I get my VM to run in a Window?

Tags: virtualbox

I am currently using Seamless mode but my VM is not really integrated into my main OS. How do I get it back into a Window?

Comment: @Diago I think he wanted to have XP in a window, not in seamless mode. At least that's what the last paragraph suggested.

Comment: @Alex - Corrected. Molly's answer remains correct however.

Comment: @Diago could be :). I only looked at the question (I also wanted to edit it, but you were faster)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I forget the name of the feature

the name of the feature is **Seamless Mode**,

> How can I get in back in a window
>   again?

Press **Host + L**, the Host key is the right **Ctrl** key by default.

Answer (score 0):

Press Host+F, where HOST is your host key, ctrl right by default.

Comment: hmmm...that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Host + F toggles Fullscreen Mode.